# JQuery selector in variable

Tags: jquery

I wanted to ask about using selector from a variable

first I have:

```
function check()
{
  $('.info input, .info select').each(function(n, element){
     if ($(element).val()=='')
     alert('empty');
  });
}
```

and called it in

```
$('input')change(check);
```

and they worked fine.

But now I want to pass some value to the function to make it dynamic, like

```
$('input')change(check('.info'));
```

and changed the function to

```
function check(sel) {   
     $(sel +' input, '+ sel + ' select').each(function(n, element){
     if ($(element).val()=='')
     alert('empty');   
  }); 
 }
```

but it doesn't work.
Any help please..
Thanks,

nagut

Comment: any errors? I can see a possible typo, `$('input')change(check('.info'));` is missing `.`, it should be `$('input').change(check('.info'));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`change` should get a function. By writing `check('.info')` you are triggering the function, and passing its result to the `change` event. Simply wrap the call in another function:

```
$('input').change(function(){check('.info');});
```

Comment: Work Successfully. Thanks Kobi.